# How to initialize NSData with array of shorts?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How do I create an instance of NSData with an array of shorts? As I understand [NSData dataWithBytes] method expects input as an array of unsigned chars?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataWithBytes:` takes a `void *`. You can pass anything you want in; just make sure you take endianness into account, if cross-architecture is an issue.

Comment: But what about the length parameter? Will the length of short array be valid here?

Comment: It will be length of the short array multiplied by `sizeof(short)`.